# Does `mapc` place a symbol on the active element of the sequence?

Tags: list

I understand that `(eq '(3 . d) '(3 . d))` returns `nil`, and `(eq 3 3)` returns `t`.  But I do not understand why `delq` is deleting one `(3 . d)` in the second example each loop when `y` is `(3 . d)`.  Is `mapc` placing some type of invisible symbol on one of the `(3 . d)` but not the others such that *only* one (1) of them in the sequence is `eq`?

```
(let* ((original '(0 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 6))
       (copy (copy-list original)))
  (mapc (lambda (x)
          (mapc (lambda (y)
                  (message "y: %s | copy: %s" y copy)
                  (setq copy (delq y copy)))
                copy))
        original))
```

In the second example, one `(3 . d)` is deleted each loop when `y` is `(3 . d)`.

```
(let* ((original '((0 . a) (1 . b) (2 . c) (3 . d) (3 . d)
                   (3 . d) (3 . d) (4 . e) (5 . f) (6 . g)))
       (copy (copy-list original)))
  (mapc (lambda (x)
          (mapc (lambda (y)
                  (message "y: %s | copy: %s" y copy)
                  (setq copy (delq y copy)))
                copy))
        original))
```

<sub>Note: `copy-sequence` is an alternative to `copy-list` a.k.a. `cl-copy-list` (defined in `cl.el`).</sub>

Comment: `C-h S copy-sequence` detailedly explains the "copy" behavior, though unlike `copy-list`, it doesn't work for dotted list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you basically explained what's going on when you explained the
`eq` business: In the first loop, the first time you hit a `3`, `delq`
removes all the `3`s, because they are `eq` to each other. In the
second loop, each time you hit a `(3 . d)`, the call to `delq` removes
that particular `(3 . d)` and not the other `(3 . d)` because they are
not `eq` to each other.

I guess you want to know how Emacs implements cons cells and `eq` to
make different occurrences of `(3 . d)` not be `eq` to each other.
Every time you evaluate a `(3 . d)`, Emacs allocates some fresh,
unused portion of memory for a cons cell and sets the `car` to `3` and
the `cdr` to `d`, for cons cells `eq` tests whether or not they are
stored in the same location in memory (if you are familiar with
pointers, as they occur in C, for example, you'd say that for cons
cells `eq` performs a pointer equality test). So there's no "extra
symbol" required to make `eq` work that way.

(Strictly speaking to explain the results you also need to know that
`copy-list` allocates new space for the list it returns, but reuses
exactly the same contents as the input list.)

Comment: Would it be accurate for me state?:  "The active element during each `mapc` loop will always be `eq` to the corresponding element of the SEQUENCE, even if the `eq` test would otherwise fail outside of a `mapc` context.  The active element may be `eq` to more than one element if they would otherwise be `eq`."

Comment: This has nothing to do with `mapc`.  The expression  `(eq '(d . 3) '(d . 3))` *may* evaluate to true because the Lisp-reader *may* create only one copy for multiple equal cells.  You can see this with something like `(progn (setq x '(a . 0) y '(a . 0)) (setcar x 'b) y)`.

Comment: See politza's comment answering yours, @lawlist (I think he or she forgot to ping you).

Comment: @politza In CL `(eq '(d . 3) '(d . 3))` can return `t`. It is detailed in the CL specification that equal constant lists can be identified. Whether that is the case for Elisp is currently an open question. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/45820/2370. For me it looks like that is unspecified for Elisp. Note that the evaluation of your example `(progn (setq x '(a . 0) y '(a . 0)) (setcar x 'b) y)` in an Org Elisp-source code block returns `(a . 0)`.