# Local variable's state mutated across function calls

Tags: local-variables, let-binding

I was surprised to discover that a local variable can have it's state modified across function invocations.  Consider the following example.

```
(defun example-mutable ()
  (let ((x '("the" "quick" "brown" "fox")))
    (nbutlast x 1)))
```

`nbutlast` is documented as follows:

> This is a version of `butlast` that works by destructively modifying the cdr of the appropriate element, rather than making a copy of the list

(And `butlast` is a function removes the last `n` elements from a list.)

Then multiple calls to `example-mutable` will return `("the" "quick" "brown")`, `("the" "quick")`, `("the")`, and nil, in that order.

Another example is the following:

```
(defun example-nonmutable (change-val)
  (let ((x '("the" "quick" "brown" "fox")))
    (when change-val
      (setq x "something else"))
    x))
```

Then calling `(example-nonmutable t)` followed by `(example-nonmutable nil)` yields results of `"something else"` and `("the" "quick" "brown" "fox")`.  So we see that in the first example the value of `x` is not rebound on repeat function invocations, while contrastingly in the second example it is rebound.

So I am guessing that when the function is called that Emacs looks at the address of the data that `x` is bound to, and if it hasn't been changed, then it doesn't bother to create a new data object and rebind it in the interest of efficiency?

Is this behavior documented in the manual or elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quoted list is a constant thus should not be modified, if you modify a constant inside a function, the function will be [self-modifying code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code), for example,

```el
;; Return how many this function is called
(defun counter ()
  (cl-incf (car '(0))))

(counter)
;; => 1

(counter)
;; => 2

(counter)
;; => 3
```

The function returns a different value each time it runs, because we are modifying the quoted constant list, `'(0)`, thus the function definition is keeping changing

```el
(symbol-function 'counter)
;; => (lambda nil (setcar (quote (3)) (+ (car (quote (3))) 1)))

(counter)
;; => 4

(symbol-function 'counter)
;; => (lambda nil (setcar (quote (4)) (+ (car (quote (4))) 1)))
```

According to my experience, it's fine to modify a quoted constant list outside a function, and you can see a lot of them in the elisp manual, e.g.,

```el
(setq l '(1 2 3))
;; => (1 2 3)

(setcar l 100)
;; => 100

(let ((l '(1 2 3)))
  (cl-incf (car l))
  l)
;; => (2 2 3)
```

Not only quoted constant list, you should also not modify literal vector and string, such as, `[1 2 3]` and `"hello"`. If you need to modify a list or vector, you need use `(list 1 2 3)` and `(vector 1 2 3)`, instead of `'(1 2 3)` and `[1 2 3]`.

Related question:
[When to use quote for lists? Modifying quoted lists in Elisp](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45820/when-to-use-quote-for-lists-modifying-quoted-lists-in-elisp)