# Unexpected behavior when updating alist

Tags: association-lists

Question: The code is below, the contents of the list `myList` were copied in the debugger.

```el
(let* ((myList '(("Concept Index"
                  ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi")
                  ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Concept Index")
                  ("спсСсылок"))
                 ("Function Index"
                  ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi")
                  ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Function Index")
                  ("спсСсылок"))
                 ("Variable Index"
                  ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi")
                  ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Variable Index")
                  ("спсСсылок"))
                 ("Reserved Word Index"
                  ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi")
                  ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Reserved Word Index")
                  ("спсСсылок"))
                 ("Builtin Index"
                  ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi")
                  ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Builtin Index")
                  ("спсСсылок"))
                 ("Indexes"
                  ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi")
                  ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Indexes")
                  ("спсСсылок"))
                 ("GNU Free Documentation License"
                  ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi")
                  ("ТочкаНоды" "@node GNU Free Documentation License")
                  ("спсСсылок"))
                 ("Major Differences From The Bourne Shell"
                  ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi")
                  ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Major Differences From The Bourne Shell")
                  ("спсСсылок"))
                 ("Reporting Bugs"
                  ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi")
                  ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Reporting Bugs")
                  ("спсСсылок"))
                 ("Optional Features"
                  ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi")
                  ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Optional Features")
                  ("спсСсылок"))))
       (текАссоц (assoc "спсСсылок" (assoc "Optional Features" myList)))
       (текСписСсылок (cdr текАссоц)))
  (setcdr текАссоц (add-to-list 'текСписСсылок "hudoSsulka"))
  myList)
```

The code fulfills as expected: in the associative list with the association `"Optional Features"`, in the associative list with the association

```
"спсСсылок"
```

the element

```
"hudoSsulka"
```

is added.

However, with the following code:

```el
(let* ((myList спЯкрНд)
       (текАссоц (assoc "спсСсылок" (assoc (match-string-no-properties 1) myList)))
       (текСпсСсылок (cdr текАссоц)))
  (setcdr текАссоц (add-to-list (quote текСпсСсылок) (match-string-no-properties 0)))
  myList)
```

all indiscriminately the parent of the

```
"спсСсылок"
```

association is populated. Why does this happen?
what happens with the list when changing one specific nested list

```
(("Function Index" ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi") ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Function Index") ("спсСсылок" "@ref{Bash Features}")) ("Variable Index" ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi") ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Variable Index") ("спсСсылок" "@ref{Bash Features}")) ("Reserved Word Index" ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi") ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Reserved Word Index") ("спсСсылок" "@ref{Bash Features}")) ("Builtin Index" ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi") ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Builtin Index") ("спсСсылок" "@ref{Bash Features}")) ("Indexes" ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi") ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Indexes") ("спсСсылок" "@ref{Bash Features}")) ("GNU Free Documentation License" ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi") ("ТочкаНоды" "@node GNU Free Documentation License") ("спсСсылок" "@ref{Bash Features}")) ("Major Differences From The Bourne Shell" ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi") ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Major Differences From The Bourne Shell") ("спсСсылок" "@ref{Bash Features}")) ("Reporting Bugs" ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi") ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Reporting Bugs") ("спсСсылок" "@ref{Bash Features}")) ("Optional Features" ("Файл" "/home/alamd/example/funEl/expirement/perevod_bash6/bash.texi") ("ТочкаНоды" "@node Optional Features") ("спсСсылок" "@ref{Bash Features}")))
```

Please look at the overall code:

```el
;;;ПлчСпсЯкр функция возвращает список якорей файлов  
(defun ПлчСпсЯкр (списокФайлов)
;;;спсЯкр переменная для списка якорей файлов в спФйл
  (let (
    (списокЯкорей (list));;;ассоциативный список нод и якорей
    (списокОглавления (list))
    (спсОбщий (list))
    ткБфр)
    (progn
;;;Перебираем список с путями к файлам
      (dolist (текИмяФайла списокФайлов списокЯкорей)
;;;Создаем буфер и сохраняем его имя
    (setq ткБфр (find-file-noselect текИмяФайла))
;;;Переключаемся в созданный буфер
    (switch-to-buffer ткБфр)
;;;Чешем в начало буфера
    (goto-char (point-min))
;;;Ищем якоря и добавляем их в список
    (while (and (< (point) (point-max))
            (re-search-forward 
;;;Ищем ноду или якорь, добавляем в список
             "^\\(?2:@node[[:space:]]+\\(?1:.+\\),?.*\\)\\|\\(?2:@anchor{\\(?1:[^}]+\\)}+?\\)" (point-max) t)
            (let ((line (match-string-no-properties 2)) (soderjanie (match-string-no-properties 1)))
              (add-to-list 'списокЯкорей `(,soderjanie ("Файл" ,текИмяФайла) ("ТочкаНоды" ,line) ("спсСсылок")))))
      )
      ;;;Ищем команды структурирования
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (and (< (point) (point-max))
            (re-search-forward 
;;;Ищем ноду или якорь, добавляем в список
             "\\(@\\(?:appendix\\(?:s\\(?:ec\\(?:tion\\)?\\|ubs\\(?:\\(?:ubs\\)?ec\\)\\)\\)?\\|chap\\(?:heading\\|ter\\)\\|heading\\|majorheading\\|s\\(?:ection\\|ub\\(?:heading\\|s\\(?:ection\\|ub\\(?:heading\\|section\\)\\)\\)\\)\\|top\\|unnumbered\\(?:s\\(?:\\(?:ubs\\(?:ubs\\)?\\)?ec\\)\\)?\\)\\)\\>.+" (point-max) t)
            (add-to-list 'списокОглавления (match-string-no-properties 0)))
      )
;;;Удаляем обработанный буфер
    (kill-buffer ткБфр)
    )
      (add-to-list 'спсОбщий (cons "Якоря" списокЯкорей))
      (add-to-list 'спсОбщий (cons "Содержание" списокОглавления))
      спсОбщий)
    )
  )
```

Part of the code when creating the list

```
(let ((line (match-string-no-properties 2)) (soderjanie (match-string-no-properties 1)))
              (add-to-list 'списокЯкорей `(,soderjanie ("Файл" ,текИмяФайла) ("ТочкаНоды" ,line) ("спсСсылок"))))
```

or should I rewrite the list overflow code?

Comment: Welcome to emacs.se. Please clarify your question. Please also edit the title of your post to give it an informative title.

Comment: As stated, your question is not reproducible or entirely clear, but I strongly suspect that you may be encountering issues due to modifying a quoted list. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/51749/15748, https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/20535/15748, and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/45814/15748. Never call `setcdr` directly on a quoted list, i.e. one created as `'(...)`. Instead, either create the list with `list`, or first make a copy of it with `copy-sequence` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I reproduced here part of the real list by copying in the debugger. In the code, this list is passed in the parameter.

Comment: @Basil In principle you are right since Common Lisp can do [Common Subexpression Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination). However, I've never seen this yet in Elisp. This is a gray area in the Elisp manual. They even use and modify the structure quoted lists in the manual. (See [my related question here on Emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45820/when-to-use-quote-for-lists-modifying-quoted-lists-in-elisp).

Comment: Which version of Emacs do you use? 1. You should not use `add-list` for `let`-bound variables. Use `cl-pushnew` instead. (Mind the order of arguments!) 2. Construct the list with `list` instead of the backquote.

Comment: GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2019-04-12

Answer (score 1):

The effect you describe occurs when you use the **same** sublist for the construction of your alist and not just equal sublists.

The **same** list remains associated to all the keys of your alist and you can **address** this same and only sublist through all keys. When you access this list through one of the keys and modify it then this modification is **visible** through all entries of the alist.

There follows a simplified example.
At first we define the `SUBLIST`. Afterwards we construct an alist with the keys `1`, `2` to which we associate the same `SUBLIST`. Afterwards we modify the list associated to `2` by overwriting `a` with `A`.

```el
(let* ((SUBLIST '(a b))
       (alist (mapcar (lambda (x)
               (cons x SUBLIST))
             '(1 2))))
  (setcar (cdr (assoc 2 alist)) 'A)
  alist)
```

The result is:

```el
((1 A b) (2 A b))
```

We see the same modified sublist `(A b)` associated to both keys `1` and `2`.

The cure to your problem is simple: Don't associate the same list to all keys but only copies of it:

```el
(let* ((SUBLIST '(a b))
       (alist (mapcar (lambda (x)
               (cons x (seq-copy SUBLIST)))
             '(1 2))))
  (setcar (cdr (assoc 2 alist)) 'A)
  alist)
```

Now you get the results as you expect them:

```el
((1 a b) (2 A b))
```

Another warning is in place if you have nested alists:
`(setq COPY (seq-copy SUBLIST))` produces a **shallow** copy of your list `SUBLIST`. If some `car` of the conses of `SUBLIST` contains a list `CARLIST` then only the link to `CARLIST` is copied not `CARLIST` itself.
If you actually want copies of `CARLIST` in `COPY` you should use `cl-copy-tree` instead of `seq-copy`.

---

A variation of the theme are quoted lists in loops.
If you push a quoted list on a list within a loop you just push the same link there multiple times.
This is demonstrated with the next example code:

```el
(let (ret)
  (dotimes (i 3)
    (push (cons i '(a b)) ret))
  (setf (nth 1 (car ret)) 'A)
  ret)
```

The result shows that 0,1,2 are all associated with the same list.
If the value corresponding to key 2 is modified. The new value can be accessed through all keys.

```el
((2 A b) (1 A b) (0 A b))
```

The following example code demonstrates that back-quotes apparently do not have this property.
Albeit, the doc string of `backquote` actually suggests that if no comma operator is used in the back-quoted list the back-quoted list should act like a quoted list.

```el
(let (ret)
  (dotimes (i 3)
    (push (cons i `(a b)) ret))
  (setf (nth 1 (car ret)) 'A)
  ret)
```

Only the value corresponding to the first key is changed:

```el
((2 A b) (1 a b) (0 a b))
```

For completeness the doc string of `backquote`:

> The whole structure acts as if it were quoted except for certain
>   places where expressions are evaluated and inserted or spliced in.
>
> For example:
>
> b              => (ba bb bc)      ; assume b has this value
>   `(a b c)       => (a b c)        ; backquote acts like quote
>   `(a ,b c)      => (a (ba bb bc) c)   ; insert the value of b
>   `(a ,@b c)     => (a ba bb bc c) ; splice in the value of b
>
> Vectors work just like lists.  Nested backquotes are permitted.

---

Now some words about your example.
I have rewritten your code as self-contained example. No need of external files:

```el
(defun get-anchor-list ()
  "Demonstrate the effects of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54050/unexpected-behavior-when-updating-alist."
  (let* ((file-list '(("file1.info" "@chapter{One11}This marks the @anchor{x-spot12}spot.\nThis marks the @anchor{x-spot13}spot.@section{Second}@node{lastNode14}")
              ("file2.info" "@chapter{One21}This marks the @anchor{x-spot22}spot.\nThis marks the @anchor{x-spot23}spot.@section{Second}@node{lastNode24}")))
     (anchor-list (list))
     (toc (list))
     (overall-list (list))
     tex-buffer
     info-file-name)
    (dolist (info-file file-list)
      (setq info-file-name (car info-file))
      (with-temp-buffer
    (insert (cadr info-file))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (and (< (point) (point-max))
            (re-search-forward 
             "^\\(?2:@node[[:space:]]+\\(?1:.+\\),?.*\\)\\|\\(?2:@anchor{\\(?1:[^}]+\\)}+?\\)" (point-max) t)
            (let ((line (match-string-no-properties 2))
              (soderjanie (match-string-no-properties 1)))
              (add-to-list 'anchor-list `(,soderjanie ("File" ,info-file-name) ("Node Point" ,line) ("Reference")))))
      )
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (and (< (point) (point-max))
            (re-search-forward 
             "\\(@\\(?:appendix\\(?:s\\(?:ec\\(?:tion\\)?\\|ubs\\(?:\\(?:ubs\\)?ec\\)\\)\\)?\\|chap\\(?:heading\\|ter\\)\\|heading\\|majorheading\\|s\\(?:ection\\|ub\\(?:heading\\|s\\(?:ection\\|ub\\(?:heading\\|section\\)\\)\\)\\)\\|top\\|unnumbered\\(?:s\\(?:\\(?:ubs\\(?:ubs\\)?\\)?ec\\)\\)?\\)\\)\\>.+" (point-max) t)
            (add-to-list 'toc (match-string-no-properties 0))))
    ))
    (add-to-list 'overall-list (cons "Anchor" anchor-list))
    (add-to-list 'overall-list (cons "Content" toc))
    overall-list))

(get-anchor-list)
```

If you instrument `get-anchor-list` with `edebug` and step forwards up to the last occurence of `overall-list` you get:

```el
(("Content" "@section{Second}@node{lastNode24}" "@chapter{One21}This marks the @anchor{x-spot22}spot." "@section{Second}@node{lastNode14}" "@chapter{One11}This marks the @anchor{x-spot12}spot.")
("Anchor" ("x-spot23" (#1="File" #2="file2.info")
(#3="Node Point" "@anchor{x-spot23}") . #4=(("Reference")))
("x-spot22" (#1# #2#)
(#3# "@anchor{x-spot22}") . #4#)
("x-spot13" (#1# #5="file1.info")
(#3# "@anchor{x-spot13}") . #4#)
("x-spot12" (#1# #5#)
(#3# "@anchor{x-spot12}") . #4#)))
```

The most interesting part is that Elisp takes the list `#4=(("Reference"))` and re-uses it in the successive lists. These are references to the same list. If you modify the list `#4` through on of its links you see this modification through all links.

You can avoid this effect by generating new lists from scratch with `list` and `cons`. There follows the modified code:

```el
(defun get-anchor-list ()
  "Demonstrate the effects of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54050/unexpected-behavior-when-updating-alist."
  (let* ((file-list '(("file1.info" "@chapter{One11}This marks the @anchor{x-spot12}spot.\nThis marks the @anchor{x-spot13}spot.@section{Second}@node{lastNode14}")
              ("file2.info" "@chapter{One21}This marks the @anchor{x-spot22}spot.\nThis marks the @anchor{x-spot23}spot.@section{Second}@node{lastNode24}")))
     (anchor-list (list))
     (toc (list))
     (overall-list (list))
     tex-buffer
     info-file-name)
    (dolist (info-file file-list)
      (setq info-file-name (car info-file))
      (with-temp-buffer
    (insert (cadr info-file))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (and (< (point) (point-max))
            (re-search-forward 
             "^\\(?2:@node[[:space:]]+\\(?1:.+\\),?.*\\)\\|\\(?2:@anchor{\\(?1:[^}]+\\)}+?\\)" (point-max) t)
            (let ((line (match-string-no-properties 2))
              (soderjanie (match-string-no-properties 1)))
              (cl-pushnew  (list soderjanie
                     (list "File" info-file-name)
                     (list "Node Point" line)
                     (list "Reference"))
                   anchor-list)))
      )
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (and (< (point) (point-max))
            (re-search-forward 
             "\\(@\\(?:appendix\\(?:s\\(?:ec\\(?:tion\\)?\\|ubs\\(?:\\(?:ubs\\)?ec\\)\\)\\)?\\|chap\\(?:heading\\|ter\\)\\|heading\\|majorheading\\|s\\(?:ection\\|ub\\(?:heading\\|s\\(?:ection\\|ub\\(?:heading\\|section\\)\\)\\)\\)\\|top\\|unnumbered\\(?:s\\(?:\\(?:ubs\\(?:ubs\\)?\\)?ec\\)\\)?\\)\\)\\>.+" (point-max) t)
            (cl-pushnew (match-string-no-properties 0) toc)))
    ))
    (add-to-list 'overall-list (cons "Anchor" anchor-list))
    (add-to-list 'overall-list (cons "Content" toc))
    overall-list))

(get-anchor-list)
```

If you `edebug` this code you get as value of `overall-list`:

```el
(("Content" "@section{Second}@node{lastNode24}" "@chapter{One21}This marks the @anchor{x-spot22}spot." "@section{Second}@node{lastNode14}" "@chapter{One11}This marks the @anchor{x-spot12}spot.")
("Anchor" ("x-spot23" (#1="File" #2="file2.info")
(#3="Node Point" "@anchor{x-spot23}")
(#4="Reference"))
("x-spot22" (#1# #2#)
(#3# "@anchor{x-spot22}")
(#4#))
("x-spot13" (#1# #5="file1.info")
(#3# "@anchor{x-spot13}")
(#4#))
("x-spot12" (#1# #5#)
(#3# "@anchor{x-spot12}")
(#4#))))
```

Contrary to the previous case the string `#4="Reference"` is reused and no longer structural element of the list.

Alternatively you can deep-copy the tree structure with `cl-copy-tree` getting the same result:

```el
(defun get-anchor-list ()
  "Demonstrate the effects of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54050/unexpected-behavior-when-updating-alist."
  (let* ((file-list '(("file1.info" "@chapter{One11}This marks the @anchor{x-spot12}spot.\nThis marks the @anchor{x-spot13}spot.@section{Second}@node{lastNode14}")
              ("file2.info" "@chapter{One21}This marks the @anchor{x-spot22}spot.\nThis marks the @anchor{x-spot23}spot.@section{Second}@node{lastNode24}")))
     (anchor-list (list))
     (toc (list))
     (overall-list (list))
     tex-buffer
     info-file-name)
    (dolist (info-file file-list)
      (setq info-file-name (car info-file))
      (with-temp-buffer
    (insert (cadr info-file))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (and (< (point) (point-max))
            (re-search-forward 
             "^\\(?2:@node[[:space:]]+\\(?1:.+\\),?.*\\)\\|\\(?2:@anchor{\\(?1:[^}]+\\)}+?\\)" (point-max) t)
            (let ((line (match-string-no-properties 2))
              (soderjanie (match-string-no-properties 1)))
              (cl-pushnew  (cl-copy-tree `(,soderjanie ("File" ,info-file-name) ("Node Point" ,line) ("Reference")))
                   anchor-list)))
      )
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (and (< (point) (point-max))
            (re-search-forward
             "\\(@\\(?:appendix\\(?:s\\(?:ec\\(?:tion\\)?\\|ubs\\(?:\\(?:ubs\\)?ec\\)\\)\\)?\\|chap\\(?:heading\\|ter\\)\\|heading\\|majorheading\\|s\\(?:ection\\|ub\\(?:heading\\|s\\(?:ection\\|ub\\(?:heading\\|section\\)\\)\\)\\)\\|top\\|unnumbered\\(?:s\\(?:\\(?:ubs\\(?:ubs\\)?\\)?ec\\)\\)?\\)\\)\\>.+" (point-max) t)
            (cl-pushnew (match-string-no-properties 0) toc)))
    ))
    (add-to-list 'overall-list (cons "Anchor" anchor-list))
    (add-to-list 'overall-list (cons "Content" toc))
    overall-list))

(get-anchor-list)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It turns out I did not create the list correctly?

Comment: @uanr81 Your alist-tree contains `("спсСсылок")` several times. That and the effect you are describing leads me to the guess that in the code you have not shown us you actually use the **same** list as value for several keys. You can change this list through one of the keys but the modified list will be visible through all the keys with the same associated list.

Comment: @uanr81 I added some words about quoted and back-quoted lists. The problem would be readily explainable with a quoted list. Things are different with back-quoted lists. As the answer explains I cannot reproduce the problem with the simple example using backquotes. But, for an example the constant tail of a back-quoted form could be realized with a quote. Therefore you actually could have the same problems with back-quotes as you have with quotes. The example says that this is not so. But, maybe that changes with byte-compiled code. Did you byte-compile your code?

Comment: what needs to be changed in my code for creating the initial list, the fact is that the list under the "спсСсылок" key is initially empty

Comment: @uanr81 Two things: 1) Use `cl-pushnew` instead of `add-to-list` (see the doc string of [`add-to-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html)). 2) Use `(list ...)` and `(cons ...)` instead of the backquote.

Comment: @Tobias thanks for including comments about backquote, I needed that to copy one alist into another alist