# Colored string in mode line

Tags: faces, mode-line, colors, string

I have:

```el
(setq mode-line-end-spaces "string")
```

That displays `string` in the mode-line.
How can I get `string` in red there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a string with the appropriate face. You do that by attaching a `face` [text property](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Properties.html#Changing-Properties) to the string, giving it value of some face (predefined or defined for the specific purpose - you can look at all the predefined faces with `M-x list-faces-display` and pick one from there, or you can [define your own face](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Faces.html#Defining-Faces)).
E.g. here's a snippet to use a predefined face:

```el
(setq s (copy-sequence "sring"))
(put-text-property 0 6 'face 'custom-invalid s)
(setq mode-line-end-spaces s)
```

Comment: I understand. To generalize your answer, I'll try to write a function that, given a string, returns a propertized string.

Comment: You should not try to modify a constant string: `(setq s (copy-sequence "string"))`.

Comment: OK - edited. Here are some links to provide some context: [When to use quote for lists? Modifying quoted lists in Elisp](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45820/when-to-use-quote-for-lists-modifying-quoted-lists-in-elisp) and [Which Lisp objects are byte-compiled?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/57806/which-lisp-objects-are-byte-compiled) plus a [similar complaint by @Fólkvangr on an answer of mine that I have not fixed](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59652/is-there-a-way-to-spread-a-list-like-in-typescript-or-golang).

Answer (score 4):

@NickD provided a good answer: use a face.

OP's comment to Nick's answer says that he'll try to write a function that, given a string, returns a propertized string.  Such functions already exist: `propertize` does that, and so does `add-face-text-property`.

For example:

```lisp
(setq ss  (propertize "abcde" 'face '(:foreground "red")))
```

or

```lisp
(setq ss  "abcde")
(add-face-text-property 0 (length ss) '(:foreground "red") nil ss)
```

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks.

Comment: You should not try to modify a literal string: `(setq ss (copy-sequence "abcde"))`.

Comment: @Fólkvangr: Depends on what behavior you want. Do you want to modify a copy of the original string or the original string? The example of using a literal string here is also for brevity - who knows where the actual original string comes from? But if the intention is to modify the original string, then you don't want to use `copy-sequence`.

Comment: @Drew: `copy-sequence` allows to create a mutable string (c.f. Elisp manual version 27, section 2.9 Mutability). In your sample code, `add-face-text-property` modifies a literal string.

Comment: @Fólkvangr: Yes, I know. And? If you can modify something then it's mutable. But all of this is extraneous. If you prefer, read *"Suppose that the value of `ss` is a string"*, instead of the `setq`. The point of the answer is that you can use `add-face-text-property` to add color to a string.