# How to change color of "font-lock-add-keywords"?

Tags: font-lock

I found this piece of code to change org-mode list elements from dashes (-) to circles (•):

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
                          '(("^ *\\([-]\\) "
                             (0 (prog1 () (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) "•"))))))
```

It works wonderfully, but I cannot figure out how to change the color of the circle to red. I tried reading the documentation of font-lock-add-keywords, but the syntax seems quite cryptic to me. Any help, pointers towards more information, or suggestions on how to achieve what I want would be most welcome.

**EDIT:**

Based on NickD's comment and on [a blog post by Kitchin on colorizing strings](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/09/14/Colorized-text-in-Emacs/), I ended up with the following:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
   'org-mode
   '(("^ *\\([-]\\) "
      (0 (prog1 () (compose-region
                    (match-beginning 1)
                    (match-end 1)
                    (propertize "•" 'font-lock-face '(:foreground "red"))))))))
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick. I guess the `compose-region` function must be ignoring any text properties, as inserting the propertized string directly in the buffer does work.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Add properties to the "•" string - see e.g. [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59794/colored-string-in-mode-line).

Comment: Thanks @NickD. I did add properties to the string, but when inserted in the org-buffer, it seems to be fontified according to whatever "higher priority" face org determines the current location/context to have. If I insert it within an org-link, for example, it'll be coloured according to org-link, and not its inherent property. Would you know of a way around that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Elisp code below shows how it can be done.
First, some notes:

1. You can use the [`display` text property](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Replacing-Specs.html#Replacing-Specs) to replace characters visually with other text.
2. If you want to display the bullet in red, propertize the replacement text. You can use [text properties in strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Props-and-Strings.html) for that purpose.
3. Use the `OVERRIDE` flag `prepend` or `append` for the [font lock keyword](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html). This is the most sensible choice if you modify an existing mode through personal configuration. It ensures that the fontification of the original mode and your own fontification is combined and none of the two overrides the other completely. If you do not add this `OVERRIDE` flag and prepend your own fontification to that one of the original mode your fontification prevents tweaks by the original mode. If you append your fontification without `OVERRIDE` it has no effect if the original mode fontifies the same stretch of text.
4. Add the keyword at the end of `font-lock-keywords` so that your fontification is not overridden by other rules (`HOW` argument of [`font-lock-add-keywords`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Customizing-Keywords.html#Customizing-Keywords)).
5. Note, a regexp as matcher is not sufficient since it also gives false positives. For an example, matches in source blocks are also highlighted. That is the reason why I introduced the matcher function `org+-match-item-marker`.

```el
(require 'org-element)
(defun org+-match-item-marker (bound)
  "Match the bullet of itemizations."
  (and
   (re-search-forward "^ *\\(-\\) " bound t)
   (save-match-data
     (save-excursion
       (goto-char (match-end 1))
       (eq (org-element-type (org-element-at-point)) 'item)))))

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'org-mode
 '((org+-match-item-marker ;; matcher
    (1 ;; subexpression
     '(face default display #("•" 0 1 (face (:foreground "red")))) ;; face
     append ;; override
     )))
 t) ;; how
```

Comment: this is brilliant. Thanks! Why do we have to add the append flag? It seems to work without it too.

Comment: @dangom I added the explanation to item 3.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complementary answer to the one posted by Tobias. I noticed that the following worked for me too:

```el
(setq red-unicode-dot (propertize "•" 'font-lock-face '(:foreground "red")))
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   'org-mode
   '(("^ *\\([-]\\) "
      (0 (prog1 () (put-text-property
                    (match-beginning 1)
                    (match-end 1)
                    'display red-unicode-dot))))))
```