# When is it better to use the backquote, `(…), and when to use (list …)?

Tags: list

The docstring for `quote` says,

> Quoting should be reserved for constants that will never be modified by side-effects, unless you like self-modifying code.

Are there cases in which it is the best choice instead?

Are there any cases in which `list` should be avoided?

---

I've asked this question to complement [When to use quote for lists? Modifying quoted lists in Elisp](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45820/when-to-use-quote-for-lists-modifying-quoted-lists-in-elisp), which is mostly about the potential drawbacks of using `quote`. What I'd like to know is not only when it is ok to use it, but if there are cases in which it is the best choice over `list` or `cons`.

---

**PS** This question was originally about `quote` and `list`, then Dan made me realize I had conflated `quote` and `backquote` in my mind. The functions I was actually confused about were `backquote` and `list`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use quote for lists? Modifying quoted lists in Elisp](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45820/when-to-use-quote-for-lists-modifying-quoted-lists-in-elisp)

Comment: IMO, general, open questions about when something is better, or what is the best, or what are the pros & cons of XYZ are too broad for this Q&A site, and they solicit discussion or opinion-based answers. A specific how-to or specific conceptual/understanding question is more helpful.

Comment: @Drew In my opinion a lot of questions with interesting answers in the network are closed because they're too broad or something like that. My question is not "specific how-to" but I'd say it's rather "specific conceptual/understanding".

Comment: @Drew The question you propose as being a duplicate does not talk about `backquote`, which is what this question is about.

Comment: At this point maybe I should change the title instead of asking another question.

Comment: @ArchStanton Yes please.

Comment: To me, your question is not at all a _specific_ conceptual/understanding question: **"What I'd like to know is not only when it is ok to use it, but if there are cases in which it is the best choice over list or cons."**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there cases in which [`backquote`] is the best choice

Yes, when constructing complex list expressions that involve a lot of quoting, unquoting, and splicing.  The best example of this is macro bodies.  See the example in [`(info "(elisp) Defining Macros")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Macros.html):

```el
(defmacro t-becomes-nil (variable)
  `(if (eq ,variable t)
       (setq ,variable nil)))
```

Without backquoting, this would be:

```el
(defmacro t-becomes-nil (variable)
  (list 'if (list 'eq variable t)
        (list 'setq variable nil)))
```

which is far harder to grok.  The problem becomes even more pronounced when splicing (`,@`) lists in the middle of other lists, as `list` and `cons` become insufficient, and `append` is needed as well.

> Are there any cases in which `list` should be avoided?

TL;DR: No.  `list` and `cons` are the fundamental building blocks of Elisp, and are implicitly and explicitly used everywhere all the time.

The only reason to prefer `backquote` over `list` is for readability.

The only reason to avoid `list` altogether is when you know for certain that some code, e.g. in a tight loop, doesn't strictly need a freshly allocated cons, and you want to reduce the amount of garbage created for performance reasons.  But this is rare and as always should be profiled and analysed carefully.

Comment: Does the suggestion about not modifying quoted lists apply to backquoted ones too?

Comment: @ArchStanton Depends on its expansion: sometimes it expands to `quote`, and sometimes to `list` or similar.  Only modify a list constructed with `backquote` if you're sure it's mutable.  See [`(info "(elisp) Backquote")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html).

Answer (score 1):

Quoted values are established at read-time, and so incur no eval-time cost to build.  So there ought to be a slight efficiency benefit to using a quoted value in cases where it's safe to do that.

It it's a genuinely constant value, then quoting is the best choice.

> Are there any cases in which `list` should be avoided?

`quote` returns the same<sup>1</sup> value every time, while `list` and `cons` build a new value every time; so obviously don't use `list` or `cons` if you're writing code which needs to see the *same* value each time.

That aside, if you didn't *need* to create the list at eval-time, then it *could* potentially be confusing to the reader if you were doing so.

---

<sup>1</sup> For a lisp-based definition of "same".

Comment: The lisp-based definition of "same" baffles me… :-)

Comment: @ArchStanton It's just a byte-compiler optimisation, similar to read-only `char*` in C, and well-known compiler optimisations like constant folding, expression elimination, etc.

Comment: Mostly it was a reference to the different kinds of equality in lisp.  The value will be `eq` to the original value, but not necessarily `equal` if it has been modified in the interim.  The classic example being that, over time, the exact same cons cell could represent very different lists.

Answer (score 0):

`list` and `quote` do not function in the same way.  `list`
evaluates its arguments, and quote does not:

```
(list 1 2 (+ 1 2))                      ; => (1 2 3)
(quote (1 2 (+ 1 2)))                   ; => (1 2 (+ 1 2))
```

Comment: I forgot to mention `backquote`! Sorry, I had conflated `quote` and `backquote` in my mind.

Comment: Please see the update and the comment to the question.